# Why are my .htaccess rules not working?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a cascade problem with my **.htaccess** rules. Consider the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$  product.php  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          index.php    [L]
```

With the above, if I requested a URL like **http://example.com/product/product-slug**, then I’d expect the request to get routed to **product.php**. However, it doesn’t; my **index.php** script is picked the request up.

I would have thought that the first `RewriteRule` would be matched, and as it has a `L` (last) flag that no further `RewriteRule`s would be matched, including the “catch-all” one at the bottom.

Why is this not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should sort it:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ product.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !product.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

The problem is that because the rules were in different sets, i.e. not attached a condition, it only stopped processing the current set of rules (the first one) and jumped onto the second.

Hope that clears it all up :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a typo in your code?  You're writing "http://example.com/products/" in your question, but in the code you're targeting `^product$`, with no s.

Also, your first rule is too strict.  It will only match http://example.com/product/.  You need to include a wild card after product to allow it to pick up product-slug.  Something like `RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$  product.php  [L,QSA]` should work.

Comment: Unfortunately these don’t seem to be the culprits. I’ve removed the typo and added the wildcard (which I missed) but a request for **/product/test** is still getting passed to **index.php**.

Comment: You need to set a condition for the rules to work as they should: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because of the order you have placed the rules in? The one below will override changes to the one above it. Try changing them around.

Also, do you need to set the RewriteBase or not? Is your project on an actual domain, or locally stored in a sub-directory of the server root?

Comment: As I say, I thought the `L` flag would stop looking for matches as soon as it matched the top rule, though?